# Is there an interactive shell for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, command-line-interface, bower

Today I started to work with bower in my project in Visual Studio 2013. When I tried to run `bower init` from the Package Manager Console in VS, I got the following error:

```
PM> bower init
bower.cmd : bower ENOINT        Register requires an interactive shellIn Zeile:1 
Zeichen:1
+ bower init
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bower ENOINT   ...teractive shell:St 
   ring) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


Additional error details:
Note that you can manually force an interactive shell with --config.interactive
```

Apparently the command needs an interactive shell to ask the user about some setting preferences, so I ended up running it outside of VS in Powershell (which is not really great).

The Package Manager Console only seems to provide non-interactive functionality (in the style of "fire and forget"). I searched for a plugin for VS that provides an interactive shell, but had no success.

**Is there any interactive shell available that integrates with Visual Studio, allowing you to run an interactive script like `bower init` without having to leave the IDE?**

Comment: Try the package management console, it does more than one might think.

Comment: That's what I did, as stated in the question.